# Automatic power on in clamshell mode when AC is switched on in macbook pro 16

Tags: macbook-pro, power, closed-clamshell

I started using a 16" MacBook Pro in closed clamshell mode with an external keyboard and monitor.

My previous MacBook Pro (late 2016) would automatically power on when I power on filter with attached AC power. But this new MacBook Pro only powers on after opening and closing the lid.

Is there any way to automatically turn on the laptop when power is applied **without opening the lid**?

Comment: Ironically, this was working (70% of the times) with my MacBook Pro 16" (late 2019), but doesn't with my new MacBook M2 Pro (2023) ‍♂️

Comment: I have the same issue, but regarding an MacBook Pro (M2 Max, 2023). My CalDigit TS3 dock would power on my older MacBook Pro (Intel) in clamshell mode when I connected the thunderbolt cable to it, but I can't get my newer Macbook pro to power on in clamshell mode when I connect it to a the newer CalDigit TS4 dock.